# Выбрасывается ошибка в нативном коде

Tags: android

Как найти из за чего происходит ошибка?

```
BOOM: pid=30422 uid=10078 gid=10078 tid=30422
debuggerd: tmb file path:'/data/tombstones/tombstone_08'
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'ThL/bird77_a_cu_ics2/bird77_a_cu_ics2:4.0.4/IMM76D/1349669037:user/test-keys'
pid: 30422, tid: 30422  >>>  <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
r0 00000000  r1 00487b8c  r2 00487b8c  r3 00000000
r4 beaea478  r5 beaea4a0  r6 514ca364  r7 00000b00
r8 4005b144  r9 000034b3  10 000034b2  fp 00000000
ip 50ee20a4  sp beaea420  lr 400c06ac  pc 400593e4  cpsr 40000010
#00  pc 000013e4  /system/vendor/lib/libpvrANDROID_WSEGL.so
#01  pc 000126a8  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_mutex_unlock)
code around pc:
400593c4 e3a02000 e59f3250 e08fc00c e08f1001  . ..P2..........
400593d4 e08f3003 ea000046 e59d3010 e3170a01  .0..F....0......
400593e4 e5932000 e5842010 e5932008 e5843018  . ... ... ...0..
400593f4 e5842014 0a000005 e5983000 e1a0e00f  . .......0......
40059404 e593f0d0 e3500000 13a03001 1a000000  ......P..0......
code around lr:
400c068c e5967000 e2144903 e08f3001 e5836000  .p...I...0...`..
400c069c 1a00000f f57ff05f e5965000 ebffec54  ...._....P..T...
400c06ac e2055a02 e3852001 e1500002 0a000006  .Z... ....P.....
400c06bc e5865000 e1a00006 e1a01005 e3a02001  .P........... ..
400c06cc ebfffedb e1a00004 e8bd87f0 e3a00000  ................
stack:
beaea3e0  00000000
beaea3e4  514c5498  /system/vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.mt6577.so
beaea3e8  003e7858  [heap]
beaea3ec  400ca9a8  /system/lib/libc.so
beaea3f0  00000000
beaea3f4  40259e85  /system/lib/libbinder.so
beaea3f8  00488150  [heap]
beaea3fc  00000000
beaea400  5f776e64
beaea404  beaea478  [stack]
beaea408  beaea4a0  [stack]
beaea40c  514ca364  /system/vendor/lib/hw/gralloc.mt6577.so
beaea410  00000b00
beaea414  4005b144  /system/vendor/lib/libpvrANDROID_WSEGL.so
beaea418  df0027ad
beaea41c  00000000
#01 beaea420  00000300
beaea424  beaea430  [stack]
beaea428  00000000
beaea42c  00000300
beaea430  00000000
beaea434  00000000
beaea438  00000000
beaea43c  00000000
beaea440  00000000
beaea444  50010001  /system/usr/icu/icudt46l.dat
beaea448  40255dc1  /system/lib/libbinder.so
beaea44c  0048b5d0  [heap]
beaea450  002887f8  [heap]
beaea454  beaea530  [stack]
beaea458  00288140  [heap]
beaea45c  00000001
beaea460  00288198  [heap]
beaea464  00288198  [heap]
```

Answer (score 1):

signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000

У вас возникает Null Pointer Exception - посмотри все ли объекты инициализируются

Comment: у меня достаточно много объектов, как то можно узнать какой именно объект? Пытался по логам найти, но после некоторых правок все равно начало выходить.

Comment: assert'ов навтыкайте на все обращения к объектам. а вообще можно в дебаге посмотреть

Comment: @otr23
А дебаггер запустить можете, чтобы коллстек посмотреть? Можно будет локализовать точку разыменования до функции, а там и сам объект...

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать.